# Working differently on demo and live site $f = fopen( 'php://output'

Tags: php, wordpress, fopen

I am looking at the Yopp Polls plugin.

`$f = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' )`

As I understand it this line of code should mean it downloads to the local machine. On the demo site it downloads to my local machine but on the live site which is a multisite it downloads the CSV to an uploads folder on the server.

I've checked settings and can't see anything but feel like I'm probably missing something very simple.

Comment: A live site is almost guaranteed _never_ going to let `fopen` [open anything other than actual files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen), with URLs being forbidden for extremely good security reasons.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans pretty sure that applies to the HTTP and FTP wrapper, but not the`php://` stream wrapper.

Comment: _"As I understand it this line of code should mean it downloads to the local machine."_ - it means that anything written to this pointer, will be written straight to the output buffer mechanism. No more, no less. What the system this is running on then _does_ with those output buffer contents, is a different matter.

Comment: @CBroe would you be able to advise what I should be looking to see where anything about the buffer mechanism is set please

Comment: As far as PHP core settings go, there is only https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering that I could see being _somewhat_ relevant here - but even if that was enabled, it would not explain how this would lead to actual files being created in a specific folder on the server. I am guessing that must rather be happening explicitly somewhere in the code.